# How google blocks Loadrunner while recording the script, Want to implement the same for my Sever

Tags: .net, windows, security, iis, loadrunner

[image: Not Secured Connection]

While Recording the script from Load runner , it through error `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` .

My Question , how they block the Loadrunner IP . Also I want to implement the same thing for my **Server**.
 I have Windows Server 12 and .net technology, so tell me what the settings need to do .

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this, but doesn't this look like you are currently encountering a man-in-the-middle attack where someone is faking Google's certificate, which your browser is warning you against? Do you have some kind of corporate proxy server that intercepts your HTTPS traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you work for Google or have written permission from Google then you should not be using any automated tools on Google.  See LoadRunner license agreement and Google License agreement regarding automation outside of their published and supported API set.

if you wish to experiment and learn to use LoadRunner on a lot of different systems then pull an open source application, install it on hardware you own, control and manage and then use that system for your experimentation.  I recommend SugarCRM and Drupal as excellent targets.

Comment: James Pulley, Tnx for your suggestion and concern, Here my motive is not to put any kind of Load on Google , also not to crack their security , My Question is **How can I make my system like Google , so that nobody can put Load on my server,or how to block any third party IP or intermediate IP**. Read my question again **"My Question , how they block the Loadrunner IP . Also I want to implement the same thing for my Server. I have Windows Server 12 and .net technology, so tell me what the settings need to do ."**

Comment: They don't block the LoadRunner IP.  The error message is from your browser recognizing that the certificate for the host that it is connecting to (proxy recorder) does not match the destination requested.  It is a security enforcement at the browser layer, not the site layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can achieve this by implementing SSL for your website. This ensures the HTTP traffic flow between your server and receiver's client is secured.

Implementation of SSL varies for server to server.
To get more idea, please refer following URLs
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Apache-WebDAV-LDAP-HOWTO/ssl.html

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation.htm

Tit Bit: Even Loadrunner allows you to record the secure traffic, if you have the digital certificate to decrypt the Secure HTTP (HTTPS) data.